# How to executeUpdate on specific event?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc

I am trying to execute an update saying:

If the current time is after than the auction end time (i.e. inactive), then set the `status` column of table `auctions` to `0`. Otherwise, set to '1'.

```
rs = st.executeQuery("select * from auctions");
System.out.println("### TESTING DATETIMES ####");
while(rs.next()){
    Timestamp start = rs.getTimestamp("startdatetime");
    Timestamp current = Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now().format(formatter));
    Timestamp end = rs.getTimestamp("enddatetime");

    int auctionID = rs.getInt("aucID");

    System.out.println(start);
    System.out.println(current);
    System.out.println(end);

    boolean inactive = current.after(end);
    System.out.println(inactive);

    if(current.after(end)){
        System.out.println("Inactive");
        st.executeUpdate("UPDATE auctions SET status='inactive' WHERE aucID=" + auctionID);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Active");
        st.executeUpdate("UPDATE auctions SET status='active' WHERE aucID=" + auctionID);
    } 
}
```

I keep getting this error..

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Operation not
>   allowed after ResultSet closed

How do I go about fixing something like this?

Comment: See the duplicate for the problem. However, what you are doing is extremely inefficient. First of all, why are you selecting **all** rows? This will get progressively slower as you get more rows, while most will no longer change status as they are inactive anyway. And you could do all this with a single update statement, which is a lot faster than the N+1 queries (1 select and N updates) of your current solution requires. And I suggest that you learn about prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need to do a select here, you can do a single update statement:

```
UPDATE auctions
SET status = CASE WHEN enddatetime < NOW()
                  THEN 'inactive'
                  ELSE 'active' END
WHERE aucID = <some ID>;
```

But, I would generally recommend against this approach, because the active/inactive label is derived data, and might not be inserted.  Instead, you could be forced to run this update mulitple times, which is not optimal.  Instead, you may select this label whenever you need it.

The exact error you are getting is due to trying to use a `ResultSet` after it has been closed.  My suggestion should eliminate this, because then you would only need a single update, something like this:

```
String sql = "UPDATE auctions SET status = CASE WHEN enddatetime < NOW() ";
sql += "THEN 'inactive' ELSE 'active' END WHERE aucID = ?";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setInt(1, 123);
ps.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `executeUpdate()` after using the `ResultSet`. Assign the `auctionID`s to `ArrayList`s and iterate them later.

```
ArrayList<Integer> inactiveIDs = new ArrayList(), activeIDs = new ArrayList();

while(rs.next()){

    ... 

    if(current.after(end)){
        System.out.println("Inactive");
        inactiveIDs.add(auctionID);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Active");
        activeIDs.add(auctionID);
    } 
}

for(Integer auctionID: inactiveIDs){
    st.executeUpdate("UPDATE auctions SET status='inactive' WHERE aucID=" + auctionID);
}

for(Integer auctionID: activeIDs){
    st.executeUpdate("UPDATE auctions SET status='active' WHERE aucID=" + auctionID);
}
```